# Unable to recieve data from Raspberry Pi Pico to Windows host over USB (virtual serial port)?

Tags: raspberry-pi, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I have designed a program in Raspberry Pi Pico to read a 4x4 matrix-keypad and inform the Raspberry Pi 4 for the key detected.
I am using to send data from Raspberry Pi Pico to Raspberry Pi 4 over USB (virtual serial port). On raspberry Pi 4 I am receiving the data successfully on /dev/ACM0
I am using print command to send data.

```
print(f'Key Detected : {key_pressed})
```

While executing on Windows, I get strange behavior. As I run the program in Thonny, I get the message in shell but when I connect hyper terminal or CoolTerm I am unable to any messages.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Maybe the default settings for serial port is different in the other applications. Did you check the speed, parity, flow control, stop bits count?

Comment: Next thing could be that that you set up the app to display messages only after you receive the new line character and Windows is using two characters instead of one. (see https://superuser.com/questions/374028/how-are-n-and-r-handled-differently-on-linux-and-windows)

Comment: @Lubo, I confirmed the settings Baud : 115200; databits : 8; None Parity; 1 Stop Bit. I am receiving data in hexadecimal mode in CoolTerm. In hexadecimal mode Coolterm displays all data regardless of its encoding or line ending.